# How to do a smooth-scroll?

Tags: javascript

I have the following working code to make a element of my scrollbox visible:

```
var next = elements.item(i+1);
var xpcomInterface = scroll.boxObject.QueryInterface(
Components.interfaces.nsIScrollBoxObject);
xpcomInterface.ensureElementIsVisible(elements);
```

But I would like to make a smooth-scroll (slow or not). Any idea how to do it?

**update**

By the way, it's for Mozilla environment.

Comment: You mentioned in a comment about the xpcomInterface, and that it is for Mozilla, so this is for a firefox extension?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to just use a `setTimeout` function and just keep moving the `top` and `left` value on the element's div by a small number, until you get where you want to be.

You may want to experiment with how fast to make it move, as there is a trade-off with smooth, and the fact that it should reach the endpoint in some reasonable time.

*Update:*

I forgot, you will want to keep calling the `setTimeout` until you reach the final destination, otherwise it won't redraw the browser window.

Comment: would be easier if xpcomInterface had a isVisible() method.. I'm looking for how to check it..

Comment: there must be a way of get the [xy] of the button inside the scrollbox, and then scroll it to that [xy] using the timeout..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to do it, but here's a Chrome Extension called "[Smooth Scroll](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cccpiddacjljmfbbgeimpelpndgpoknn)" where you can potentially pick through the code to see what they do and maybe get you in the right direction.

PS I love this extension.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `.animate()` with accelerated motion [can be kind of smooth](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) (see demo for *animate with a relative move*). And [with a plug-in](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/), there are other easing equations it can use.